# Connection to EC2 instance closed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, aws-cli, ssh-tunnel

If I connect to an AWS EC2 instance with ssh and execute the corresponding statement, the connection is disconnected. It doesn't even seem to run properly for some reason.

I run at local:

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -i $AWS_KEY -t ubuntu@$INSTANCE_DNS 'cd /home/ubuntu/HW /;sudo bash ./settings.sh'

ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=300 -i $AWS_KEY -t ubuntu@$INSTANCE_DNS 'cd /home/ubuntu/HW /;sudo bash ./run_all.sh'
```

```
# run.sh
chmod +x run_dstat.sh
chmod +x run_nvidia.sh
chmod +x run_workload.sh
nohup ./run_dstat.sh >nohup.out & nohup ./run_nvidia.sh >nohup2.out & nohup ./run_workload.sh >nohup3.out &
```

```
# setting.sh
pip3 install tensorflow==2.7.0
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dstat
chmod +x run_all.sh
```

output

```
Successfully installed  ~~~~
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
rm: cannot remove '/var/cache/apt/archives/lock': No such file or directory
Hit:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                    
Hit:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                  
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                                                                
Get:5 https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1484 B]                                                  
Get:6 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/stable/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1481 B]
Get:7 https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu18.04/amd64  InRelease [1474 B] 
Hit:8 https://fsx-lustre-client-repo.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease      
Fetched 4439 B in 1s (6862 B/s)                   
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
55 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-pip-whl python3-keyring python3-keyrings.alt python3-secretstorage python3-wheel python3-xdg
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dstat
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 55 not upgraded.
Need to get 52.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 443 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 dstat all 0.7.3-1 [52.1 kB]
Fetched 52.1 kB in 0s (0 B/s)    
Selecting previously unselected package dstat.
(Reading database ... 142222 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/dstat_0.7.3-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking dstat (0.7.3-1) ...
Setting up dstat (0.7.3-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Connection to ec2-34-228-71-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
start experiment
Connection to ec2-34-228-71-59.compute-1.amazonaws.com closed.
```

The funny thing is, if you directly connect to the instance and run it, it runs normally. Why doesn't it work only when using ssh?

Comment: seems like keep alive settings issue.

Comment: @error404 As soon as it runs, the connection is cut off immediately, so it doesn't seem like a time issue. Can you give me a hint what part it is? And when I cloned Github, there was no disconnection at all. please thank you

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show exactly how you're running ssh and how you're invoking these commands inside the ssh session.

Comment: can you please run the ssh in verbose mode

Comment: @Kenster updated!

Comment: @error404 updated!

Comment: This sounds more like a MTU problem. If traffic with small packets (i.e. pinging) works, but the connections break as soon as a large packet is sent (i.e. the output from the script), then you may have a problem with MTU in your network path.